# created environments not appearing in anaconda's envs folder

Tags: pycharm, anaconda, environment

Whenever I try to create an environment in anaconda, it doesn't show up in envs. Or anywhere, but when I try making the environment again, it says that environment already exists in envs, but nothing is there.

I have tried numerous methods to fix it, but none solve my problem.

Can anybody help me?

Comment: Can you describe step by step how you create the environment?

Comment: oh im sorry i found them after doing a full c: drive scan, but thank you